# Can I give space between UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I would like to give space of 10 pixel in each table view cell.

How I can do that?

Right now all cells are coming without any space

[image]

Here is my cell function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyOrderCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);


 if (cell == nil)
 {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 }



 UILabel *orderid = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
 orderid.textColor = kMaroonColor;
 orderid.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kProductFont];
 orderid.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ORDER ID : %@",contentDict[@"order_id"]];

 UILabel *date = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
 date.textColor = kMaroonColor;
 date.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kProductFont];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:contentDict[@"order_date"]];

 // Convert date object to desired output format
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:kDateFormat1];
 NSString *dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1];
 date.text = dateStr;

 NSArray *products = contentDict[@"products"];
 UILabel *noOfProducts = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
 noOfProducts.textColor = kMaroonColor;
 noOfProducts.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kProductFont];
 noOfProducts.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO OF PRODUCTS : %d",products.count];


 NSArray *totalArray = contentDict[@"totals"];
 NSDictionary *totalDict = [totalArray objectAtIndex:0];
 UILabel *price = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:104];
 price.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 price.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kProductFont];
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u20B9 %@",totalDict[@"total"]]];
 [attributeString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                        value:kGreyColor
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
 price.attributedText = attributeString; 

 UIView* shadowView = [[UIView alloc]init];
 [cell setBackgroundView:shadowView];
 // border radius
 [shadowView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

 // border
 [shadowView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
 [shadowView.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];

 // drop shadow
 [shadowView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
 [shadowView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
 [shadowView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
 //[cell.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];
 [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
 [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
 //    [tableView setIndentationWidth:10];
 //    [tableView setIndentationLevel:2];

 //tableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
 return cell;
}
```

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure let me past the code too

Comment: make cell 10px higher and shift content down, if you want space only on top add header view

Comment: Is pretty easy, just put another view in the cell, add constraint so that its 10px from the bottom of contentview then do everything inside that view (treat it as cell's contentview), then u will got the space, don't create cell as section

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most simple way would be make your cells height a bit bigger(3pt from top and 7pt from the bottom) than that of your cell's background image, and making the colour as `[UIColor clearColor]`. That would give the illusion that the cells have a 10 pt gap in between.

Comment: Will it work with auto layout, I would like to give the background shadow at the same time and the space must come after shadow end not including shaddow

Comment: yes u can do that, just create the shadow along with the image. after the image, put the padding.

Answer (score 6):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
      // number of cells or array count
      return 10;
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewnumberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
      return 1;
    }

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
      // space between cells
       return 10;
    }

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        UIView *view = [UIView new];
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good workaround since the most implementation use multiple cells inside only one section.

Answer (score 4):

In the user interface for UITableView set Row Height Attribute value 210.
and In the user interface for UITableViewCell set Row Height Attribute value 200.

It will put 10 px space between each cell in the TableView

Answer (score 2):

just make numberOfSections = "Your array count" and make each section contains only one row. And then define headerView and its height.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return yourArry.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return cellSpacingHeight;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *v = [UIView new];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return v;
}
```

Comment: I need the background shadow at the same time, just like the screen shot I provide

Answer (score 2):

Create a container view inside UITableviewCell->ContentView. You keep all your subviews(labels,buttons,views) inside that container view. Now set container's boundaries away from the Cell's contentview by setting appropriate constraints.

> UITableviewCell->ContentView->YourCustomContainerView-> (all
>   subviews). Set YourCustomContainerView's boundaries away from the
>   ContentView.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using an accessory view. The accessory view resides in the content view and won't get added to your container view.

Comment: Apparently, this idea is for custom cells only. Just like the one shared with the question.

Comment: Custom cells can still have accessory views.

Comment: But as per my solution, 'YourCustomContainerView' will overlap the default contentView with some padding.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best way is to add a separator cell for each normal cell. let each kind of cell do its own job, and you can reuse the the separator and normal cell else where and need not to change their UI again. and you can customize the separator as you want, and all the calculations are easy, easy like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return dataArray.count * 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        CellForData *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dataCellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }else{
        CellForSeparation *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"separatorCellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If for a simple solution you can create sections for all cells. Each section each row. You can add a footer height for spacing between sections.

Comment: Creating section for each cells not seems good but yes its last solution

Answer (score 1):

its so simple
you can set the auto layout or adjust the Hight of the label
as well increases the hight of the cell

Comment: please add some more information , it is easy to understand for questioner

Answer (score 1):

Increase the cell Hight.... And hide the separator and set the background view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by having 1 cell per section & set tableview style to `Grouped`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to have sections and do not want to create mystery space within your cells, create a collection view instead of a table view. Collection Views can be set to vertical only and one column only = you can also set the minimum line height and interitem spacing. [Apple Developer Docs for UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview)

Answer (score 0):

Add UIView (childview) to ContentView.  Add 10 pixcel spacing from top and bottom to parentView. Add your cell content in childView.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I found this on internet hope this will help some future seeker
// This method should implement in custom class
// This for give space between row

override var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set (newFrame) {
        var frame =  newFrame
        frame.origin.y += 4
        frame.size.height -= 2 * 5
        super.frame = frame
    }
}
```